# how to create database in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have created an account in Ec2, but I can't understand how to upload file in ec2 server,
how to create ftp account for transfer the files and how to create MySQL database in ec2.

If any one knows, please share with me.

Comment: this is not a good programming question, should be deleted.

Answer (score 7):

Since you have an account with Amazon and EC2, you can use their console: [https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/home](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/).

In the console, click on **Instances**, then **Launch Instance** to create a new virtual machine. There are lots of operating systems to choose from; a good choice for a first instance would be 32-bit Ubuntu running on an `m1.small` instance.

If you already have a Keypair, select the one you want from the list. Otherwise, you can create a new Keypair in the **Keypair** dialog. When the new instance has been created, you can use the keypair to connect to it, using a command like:

```
ssh -i siva_keypair root@InstancePublicDNS
```

You can get the instance public DNS name from the console. At this point, you're basically logged on to a new machine, and can use it in any way you would use a real, physical machine.

By the sound of it, you're going to want to create some user accounts, install an FTP server and MySQL (use `apt-get` if you're on Ubuntu).

Note that you *can* lose data which you put on the local disk if an instance goes down - if you're running a database you should use [EBS](http://aws.amazon.com/ebs/) which is very easy to set up, and gets you persistent, fast storage which can be attached to any EC2 instance.